# How to create local server in metroUi

Tags: c#, webserver, windows-runtime

I am porting a WPF application to metroui. I need a local web server to run some of my features and I've used TinyServer in WPF
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8593/Building-a-Tiny-WebServer-in-less-than-500-lines)
However, I couldn't run it in MetroUI. Is there any way to run it, or can I create local web server in my application. (only get operation is required, I don't need post operation).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/y7cbb2y2.aspx) is an API that you can use to create a webserver in substantially less than 500 lines. Any reason why you're not using it?

Comment: I've tried to use it, however it says "The type or namespace name 'HttpListener' couldn't be found." (System.Net reference added)

Answer (score 0):

HttpListener is not supported in Win store app. But it's not hard to write a simple one with StreamSocketListener .